# Pop-up menu in Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I use Sparx Enterprise Architect 13.5 and I made MDG technology for own requirements. 
When I drag element from toolbox onto diagram with overlapping existing diagram element there is pop-up menu (see screen). 
If I use default Class object from Class toolbox everything is fine, no menu. 
How to supress menu ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default menu when you add a stereotype onto an element with the base meta-class.

In this case I suppose you extended your custom requirement stereotypes from **UML Class**?
If you extend them from another base metaclass such as Requirement you won't get this menu.

Or you can drop the requirement on an empty space in the diagram instead of on the class.

Comment: Are there any other type like Requirements with "no menu" feature ? I tryed Component, Text, Artefact  - the same as Class metatype.

Comment: Not sure, there might be other factors at play as well. I would try to play with some of the other properties to check if they make a difference.